# I can't fix broken packages

Tags: bash, mysql

I can't fix this problem. I don't know how.
I followed a tutorial on youtube and I downloaded the deb package on this site dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql and I tried installing it. It didn't work and gave me errors and packages that couldn't be installed.

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

This is what I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmysqlclient21 : Depends: mysql-common (>= 8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04) but 5.8+1.0.5ubuntu2 is installed
 mysql-community-server-core-dbgsym : Depends: mysql-community-server-core (= 8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04) but it is not installable
 mysql-community-test : Depends: mysql-community-server (= 8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04) but it is not installable
                        Depends: mysql-community-client (= 8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libmysqlclient-dev but it is not installed
                        Depends: libjson-perl but it is not installed
                        Depends: mecab-ipadic-utf8 but it is not installed
                        Depends: mysql-community-server-core but it is not installable
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

I tried removing mysql but the dependencies still remained. There is no sql anything on my linux system now. Nothing, so I don't know why it still says there are broken packages.

Comment: What did you do right before this started happening?

Comment: I tried downloading mysql server if I remember correctly

Comment: You must have done more than download it.

Comment: I followed a tutorial on youtube and I downloaded the deb package on this site https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ and I tried installing it. It didn't work and gave me errors and packages that couldn't be installed.

Comment: Try undoing what you did. Suggest that you put this information about what you did to break your system in the question as well.

Comment: Already tried. It removed mysql server, yet, told me that I have those broken packages. Now I can't install anything else

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134488/discussion-between-kesiscarlet-and-organic-marble).

Comment: "*I tried removing mysql*" -- That generally won't work. Apt can't process the removal because of the broken dependencies that block ALL apt actions. That you still encounter the problem suggests that your attempt to remove the package was not successful.

Comment: It looks like you're on an old Ubuntu and tried to install a new mysql that depends on (ie needs) newer packages than your system can find. What's your `lsb_release -a` say (or what version do you have). It looks like you have maybe version 18.xx/19.xx but you need at least 20.04 to get the dependencies you need to install that specific package.

Comment: my ubuntu version is 20.04 LTS. I installed the right version of mysql. I am stuck at this point. my pc is useless. I can't install or remove anything. I don't want to reinstall linux